# If Statement Never Ends if <> Operator is used

Tags: vba

If I run this code, where <> is the operator comparing the cell on this row to the cell on the previous row, it never ends and will continue adding rows without breaking under the first line where the condition is met.

```
Dim rRng As Range
Dim rCell As Range

Set rRng = Range("B2:B30")

For Each rCell in rRng.Cells
If InStr(1, rCell.Value, "Foo") = 2 And rCell.Value <> rCell.Offset(-1, 0).Value Then
     rCell.EntireRow.Insert
EndIf
Next rCell
```

But if I change the <> to =, it only adds the lines where both the current cell and previous cell values are "Foo".

Why is it adding more than one line? Why doesn't it ever break?

Comment: Because `rRng` grows with each inserted row, and because you do not exit the loop when the condition is first met.

Comment: But when I use = instead of <>, it doesn't continue to grow infinitely. It grows by however many rows were inserted. Why does the <> operator result in an infinite number of insertions such that rRng keeps growing?

Comment: Because when you insert a row between two adjacent rows with equal values, you break the situation where you have two equal values on adjacent rows: you now have a blank row that separates them, so on the next iteration the `=` will fail and stop. On contrary, when you add a row between two rows, one of which is `Foo` and the other isn't, the inequality situation is preserved: the `Foo` row, now pushed down, is still not equal to its now-adjacent row (the freshly inserted one) and will trigger the `<>` on the next iteration.

Comment: @GSerg You might want to consider adding your comments as answer? Yes?

Comment: @L42 I guess so, oh well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Excel a range grows when you insert a row inside it.

You first capture the initial range as "B2:B30", but after first row insertion it becomes "B2:B31", shifting all rows after the insertion point down.
Importantly, the insertion point is located before the current row, so after the insertion the inserted row takes the place of the current row, and the current row shifts down, so it will be considered again on the next iteration.

The `=` works as you expect because it requires values in two adjacent rows (the current and the previous) to be equal for the insertion to happen, and when you insert a row between the two adjacent rows with equal values, you break the situation of equality: you now have a blank row that separates them, so on the next iteration the `=` condition will not be satisfied.

On contrary, `<>` requires the values in two adjacent rows (the current and the previous) to be different, and when you insert a row between two rows, one of which is `Foo` and the other isn't, the inequality situation is preserved: the original `Foo` row, now pushed down, is still not equal to its now-adjacent row (the freshly inserted one with empty values) and will trigger the `<>` on the next iteration.